# Bind9 Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, dns

Hace 2 meses intente configurar el servidor bind9 siguiendo un tutorial pero no funciono. El día de ayer retome esta configuración desde 0 por lo cual decidí  por medio de estos comandos detener el servicio y desabilitarlo, ya que pensé que me traería problemas con la nueva configuración.

```
root@dlorenzo1:~# systemctl stop bind9
root@lorenzo1:~# systemctl disable bind9
```

Entonces instale de nuevo el bind9 pero cuando realizo el siguiente comando `root@lorenzo1:~# systemctl list-unit-files -t service` para saber si esta el servicio , no lo encuentro ahí. He intentado con los siguientes comandos para reiniciar,iniciar,habilitar pero ninguno funciona.

```
root@lorenzo1:~# systemctl start bind9
root@lorenzo1:~# systemctl enable bind9
root@lorenzo1:~# systemctl restart bind9
```

En todos me sale el siguiente mensaje que es como si el servicio no existiera.

```
failed to enable bind9.service unit: bind9.service does not exist
failed to restart bind9.service unit: bind9.service does not found
failed to start bind9.service unit: bind9.service does not found
```

Ademas pruebo el estado del servicio con el siguiente comando `service bind9 status` 
Me muestra lo siguiente `Unit bind9.service could not be found.`

Answer (score 1):

acabo de encontrar la solución. Al listar todos los servicios me di cuenta que el servicio named y el named-resolvconf estaban des-habilitados por lo cual procedí a habilitar ambos con los siguientes comandos: `systemctl enable named`   y   `systemctl enable named-resolvconf`.